# How to get sentence between open and close tag of StackPanel in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml code like this

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
    <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
    <Button>Content</Button>
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
     </Broder>
</StackPanel>
```

I am reading this conetnt as a string and want to get whole sentence after first line of StackPanel and before end of StackPanel of parent StackPanel.
I mean

```
<TextBox>Text</TextBox>
<Button>Content</Button>
<Border>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Broder>
```

How is this possible ??

Comment: In what context? Are you reading the XAML as a string from disk, or are you trying to actually parse it, or are you trying to get that part from the XAML that defined your view?

Comment: That is not valid XAML. A Border can only have a single child element, which is accessible by its `Child` property. If you want to access the child elements of a Panel (e.g. a Grid), use the `Children` property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, this is just about string parsing or using an XML-Lib, not exactely WPF related although the string parsed is XAML..

Assuming the XAML block ends with an explicit closing tag (`</StackPanel>`) and you only pass in the tag in question and not the complete XAML of your file, might roughly get along with this one, though it could be improved in some ways. Especially the lookup for the starting tag is safer when done by a Regex, to avoid mismatches with tags that extend another tag's name, like `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem`.
But for getting the inner XAML of a StackPanel it should suffice.

```
const string wholeXAML = 
@"<StackPanel x:Name=""stackPanel"">
    <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
    <Button>Content</Button>
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
     </Border>
</StackPanel>";

var innerXAML = GetInnerXAML(wholeXAML, "StackPanel");
Console.Write($"*{innerXAML}*");    


private string GetInnerXAML(string wholeXAML, string tagName) {
    var start = $"<{tagName}";
    var end = $"</{tagName}>";
    
    var sPos = wholeXAML.IndexOf(start);
    var ePos = wholeXAML.LastIndexOf(end);
    
    if (sPos < 0 || ePos < 0) return null;
    if (ePos <= sPos) return null;
    
    var innerXAML = wholeXAML.Substring(sPos + tagName.Length, ePos - sPos - tagName.Length);
    
    return innerXAML;
}
```